# i am not able to follow the following code snippet from the node beginners book

Tags: javascript, node.js

**app.js** , **server.js** and **router.js** are the 3 files

### app.js

```
var server = require('./server');
var router = require('./router'); //here we are requiring the module
server.start(router.route);
```

### server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
function  start(route){
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url);
        console.log("request for " + pathname + " recieved");

                            //in this line we are using route function  
        route(pathname);    //which is in router.js 
                            //why are we not requiring the module ie     require('./router')

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
    }
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
    console.log("Server has started.");
}
exports.start = start;
```

### router.js

```
function route(pathname){
    console.log("About to route a request for "+pathname);
}
exports.route = route;
```

why are we not requiring **router.js** in the server.js file (`require('./router');`)

Comment: Why would you? It's being required in `app.js` which also requires `server.js`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss out part of `server.js`? It seems to me `start` should have a declared parameter (and use it for something), but it doesn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes he is missing that part, but if you take that error away, the code is correct

Comment: sorry. my first question i missed that part, edited it now

Comment: If you think about it logically, it isn't the server that routes your calls, it's the app. Thus, the app itself is where the routing code should be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may see, the server.js does not require the routes.js file since it is being pass as an argument of the function start on server.js.

Being that said, I see an error in your code, the start function on server.js should have a "route" parameter.

Then when you instantiate your app.js, you require both but then when you call start and send that argument, afterwards you don't need to import routes.js again since it is already there as a reference.

Let me know if that answer your question.

Best,
Dario

Comment: Yup i did miss that parameter, thanks for the insight

Comment: Sure, anytime, javascript is a really powerful language but tricky sometimes. Hope you will get use to it, good luck with node :)

Answer (score 0):

> why are we not requiring router.js in the server.js file

Because there's no need to. `server.js` doesn't need the `router` module for anything.

The code in `app.js` calls `server`'s `start` passing in the route information as an argument. But `start` doesn't accept any parameters, so it doesn't use that argument for anything. Perhaps later in the tutorial they'll start using the routing information.

But the point is that `server.js` doesn't need to `require` it, because it receives it (or will receive it at some point when the code is updated) as a parameter to `start`.